# Detecting inactivity in fennec - firefox mobile extension

Tags: firefox-addon, fennec

I'm building an addon for firefox mobile (fennec).
Is it possible to detect if the browser is running in background or the screen is locked so that I can suspend some task that is running within my extension?

Answer (score 1):

You can also listen for the "application-foreground" and "application-background" notifications. Firefox does this itself here:

http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/mobile/android/chrome/content/browser.js#5445

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can - Fennec itself doesn't seem to care whether the screen is on or off, at least I couldn't find any code checking that. Normally I would recommend [js-ctypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/js-ctypes) to call the necessary OS functionality directly but it is of very limited use on Android. So I guess that the best thing you can do is using [nsIIdleService](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIIdleService) to detect when the user has been inactive for a while.